# Zip parallell arrays in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have parallel arrays in a hive table, like this:

```
with tbl as ( select array(1,2,3) as x, array('a','b','c') as y) 
select x,y from tbl;



x       y
[1,2,3] ["a","b","c"]
1 row selected (0.108 seconds)
```

How can I zip them together (like the python zip function), so that I get back a list of structs, like

```
[(1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3,"c")]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `posexplode` so it gives the positions in the `array` which can then be used for filtering.

```
select x,y,collect_list(struct(val1,val2))
from tbl
lateral view posexplode(x) t1 as p1,val1
lateral view posexplode(y) t2 as p2,val2
where p1=p2
group by x,y
```

Answer (score 1):

Here was my attempt at avoiding a double-explode:

```
with tbl as (select array(1,2,3,4,5) as x, array('a','b','c','d','e') as y) 
select collect_list(struct(xi, y[i-1])) 
from tbl lateral view posexplode(x) tbl2 as xi, i;
```

However, I ran into a strange error:

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: IllegalArgumentException Size requested for unknown type: java.util.Collection (state=42000,code=40000)
```

I was able to work around it using

```
set hive.execution.engine=mr;
```

which is not as fast / optimized as using spark or tez as the back end.

Comment: I am able to resolve this error in Tez with the following setting: 

`set hive.map.aggr=false;`

Comment: @Abhimanyu i did not realize that engine were still around  but in any case i can't use that trick since the overall sql's need to run in `tez`